# in a callBack function if Statement is not working;

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

Here This part of my code is not working i don't know what is the problem, and why it is not working. plese help me. this is the part where my code is not working, i tried ths similar code inside code , not exactly this one but almost similar one it worked perfectly, by this is not working.

```
function transform(){
   if ( value1.innerText== "Feet" && value2.innerText== "Meter"){
             
   } else if( value1.innerText=="Feet" && value2.innerText== "Meter"){
    console.log("hello")
   }
   else if( value1.innerText=="Meter" && value2.innerText==="Feet"){
    console.log("hello")
   }
}    `
```

```js
//LELBEL VALE SELECTION

const value1= document.querySelector(".value1");
const value2= document.querySelector(".value2");
console.log(value1.innerText, value2.innerText);

// VALUE INPUT SELECTION

const value1Input= document.querySelector(".value1-input");
const value2Input= document.querySelector(".value2-input");

//CONVERTING THIS VALUE INTO NUMBER



// Selectiong the button chhose
const choice= document.querySelector(".pickup");
const convert= document.querySelector(".convert");

console.log(choice.value);
// USING CHANGE EVENT TO CHANGE THE LEBEL VALUE
 choice.addEventListener("change", function(){

    if (choice.value==="Feet-to-Meter"){
        value1.innerText= "Feet:";
        value2.innerText= "Meter:";
    }
    if (choice.value==="Meter-to-Feet"){
        value1.innerText= "Meter:";
        value2.innerText= "Feet:";
    }
})

convert.addEventListener("click", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    return  transform();
       
})

//GRABING THE LEBEL VALUE AND USING THE CONVERT BUTTON TO GET THE RESULT

function transform(){
    if ( value1.innerText== "Feet" && value2.innerText== "Meter"){
                 
        console.log("hello");
       } else if( value1.innerText=="Feet" && value2.innerText== "Meter"){
        console.log("hello")
       }
       else if( value1.innerText=="Meter" && value2.innerText==="Feet"){
        console.log("hello")
       }
    }
```

```css
.feet-to-meter{
    width:40vw;
    height:auto;
    background:#e8c245;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -80%);
  }
  legend{
    font-family:arabic-indic;
    font-weight:900;
    font-size:1.5rem;
    padding-top: 10px;
   
  }
  form{
    height:100%;
  }
  input{
    padding:10px;
    font-size:1.1rem;
   
  }
  lebel{
   
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .variables{
    display: flex;
    align-items: cneter;
  }
  fieldset{
    border:2px solid lightcyan;
    height:65%;
    width:50%;
  }
  .pick{
    width:50%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  select{
    padding:1.2rem;
    font-size:1rem;
  }
  
  .button-group{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-around;
    width:80%;
    height:18%;
    align-items:center;
    padding-bottom:10px;
   
  }
  
  .button-group> button{
   padding: 5px 15px;
    
    
  }
  
  @media only screen and (min-width: 1328px){
    body{
      background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    }
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 999px){
    body{
        background-color: aquamarine;
    }
    .feet-to-meter{
        width:100vw;
        height:300px;
        background:#e8c245;
        overflow:hidden;
        position:absolute;
        top:90%;
        left:50%;
      
      }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="conversition.css" class="css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="feet-to-meter"> 
        
        <form>
        
      <div class="variables"> 
        
        <fieldset>
          <legend class="legend"> FEET TO METER </legend>
        
          <lebel style="margin-right:33px;" class="value1"> Feet </lebel> <input class="value1-input" type= "number"> <br/>
           
        <lebel class="value2"> Meter </lebel> <input style="margin-bottom:10px;" class="value2-input" type= "number">
        </fieldset>
        
        <div class="pick">
             
         <h2> Format 
            <select class="pickup">
              <option>  PICK YOUR FORMAT  </option>    
               <option value="Feet-to-Meter"> Feet To Meter  </option> 
               <option value="Meter-to-Feet">  Meter  To Feet </option>                    
            </select>
         </h2>
        </div>

        </div>
        
        <div class="button-group"> 
            <button class="convert"> CONVERT </button>
            <button class="meter-to-feet"> METER TO FEET </button>
        </div>
         
       
    </form>
</div>

    <script src="conversion.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there are spaces in the innerText of these selectors

```
const value1= document.querySelector(".value1");
const value2= document.querySelector(".value2");

<lebel style="margin-right:33px;" class="value1"> Feet </lebel> 
           
<lebel class="value2"> Meter </lebel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear out the whitespaces  in the innerText of your selectors.

To do this, just add the `.trim()` method in your `transform()` function to clear out the whitespaces.

Old Function

```
function transform(){
if ( value1.innerText== "Feet" && value2.innerText== "Meter"){
             
    console.log("hello");
   } else if( value1.innerText=="Feet" && value2.innerText== "Meter"){
    console.log("hello")
   }
   else if( value1.innerText=="Meter" && value2.innerText==="Feet"){
    console.log("hello")
   }
}
```

New and Improved Function.

```
    function transform() {
        if (value1.innerText.trim().includes("Feet") && value2.innerText.trim().includes("Meter")) {
            console.log("hello");
        }
        else if (value1.innerText.trim().includes("Feet") && value2.innerText.trim().includes("Meter")) {
            console.log("feet clicked")
        }
        else if (value1.innerText.trim().includes("Meter")  && value2.innerText.trim().includes("Feet")) {
            console.log("hello")
        }
    }
```

I used the `includes()` method cos your selectors also contains an extra `:` character which could cause conflict when checking string equality.

More on the .trim() method [Trim Method W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)

And
.include()
[Include Method Javascript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp)

Comment: thank you so much for your detail answer.. it helps a lot, and my problem is solved. thanks again .